# From where does "apt-get install package_name" download packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

When I run this `apt-get install package_name` in SSH, the package is installed, but from which site?

Is it http://packages.debian.org ?

I know in ruby when you run `gem intall xxx`, the gem is downloaded from rubygems.org. Not that long ago, the site was hacked and the hackers installed a payload in 1 gem. It is possible to find the gems at github and see what is going on. Rubygems also have a status.rubygems.org. Is there any similar for debian packages?

Comment: think we are talking about the wrong distro here...

Comment: I am asking which offical site are the packages downloaded from? Ubuntu server 10.04

Comment: I think they are downloaded from http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does apt-get install get packages from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394252/where-does-apt-get-install-get-packages-from)

Comment: This question is older than the question listed as being duplicated. I vote to leave this one open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type:

```
apt-cache policy package_name
```

And it'll tell you. On Ubuntu, it's usually `archive.ubuntu.com`, but you may have other sources set up.

Comment: People manage this packages at: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat /etc/apt/sources.d/*
```

should show you the repos used. I don't know how rubygems.org was protected but here is some useful pieces of advice on apt: http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt it's for debian but it also applies to Ubuntu which uses the same packet manager.