# Where does apt-get install get packages from?

Tags: apt

When I install something in the terminal, such as chromium, I would type in

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

How does the terminal know that `chromium-browser` is a valid package to install? Is there some list of all packages that can be installed? How does it find the packages?

Comment: In Ubuntu Software installation is different. It is so secured. They are installed from a trusted pool. Advanced and freely available applications which needed for majority of the functions in computing are in that pool. You can select and install from either Software Center or running `sudo apt-get install [PACKAGENAME]` command.

Comment: plz ask a single question.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you call `apt-get update` the repositories contained in the `sources.list` get read, this tells apt-get from where to get packages lists. This list get downloaded and stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists` for posterior use. These are lists of all packages available from the repositories you selected. Even if you remove your sources.list, this list will be available for APT. That's why you should always do `update` whenever you add/remove/modify a repository, to keep these lists updated.

---

#### How does the terminal know that chromium-browser is a valid package to install?

"The terminal" knows nothing. APT read all the lists in `/var/lib/apt/lists` and determine if the package is available. If the package is not found in any of the lists, you will get:

```
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

---

#### Is there some list of all packages that can be installed?

This changes from repository to repository. Your local copy/list of your active repositories is found in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

---

#### How does it find the packages?

```
$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

The line of interest is

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

which tells you that APT reads the list, from `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

Comment: Where's `sources.list`?

Comment: @alex man sources.list

Comment: What does it do once it finds it in lists?

Comment: @Goldname which list?

Comment: You look in /var/lib/apt/lists here to see if it exists. Does this just match the package to a website where it's installed from?

Comment: @Goldname backwards, it search for the packages provider by the different repositories. It's mostly a copy of the In/Release and Package files that contains the lists on the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` searches for the specified package in the repositories given in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Answer (score 0):

To show where `apt-get install` gets a specific package (e.g. chromium-browser) from, open the terminal and type:

```
apt-cache policy chromium-browser | grep $(lsb_release -sc)
```

The results will be one or two lines showing the exact update server mirror
and the exact repository from which apt and apt-get in your Ubuntu downloads the chromium-browser package. There's no need to search anywhere because it's all there in either one or two lines of output. The results of `apt-cache policy <package> | grep $(lsb_release -sc)` are printed on two lines in the case where there are two alternate repositories, otherwise they are printed on one line if there's just one repository that contains `<package>`.

Explanation:

- `$(lsb_release -sc)` is the codename for your Ubuntu release
- `apt-cache policy <package>` - prints out the priorities of each source of `<package>`